# How can I pass my LatLng from one activity to another when I use IndoorAtlas map and I calculate my position using trilateration?

Tags: android, google-maps, localization

I am using IndoorAtlas map and in another activity I calculate my position with trilateration using beacons , Kalman filter , pathloss model. The thing is I calculate my position but I don't know how to pass it to my map which is in another activity to make the blue dot be the position calculated .

Here is my final location named " center " in RangingActivity.class

```
LocationFinder locationFinder = new LocationFinder();
                    //pass location
                    LatLng center = locationFinder.findLocation(RSSI1Unfiltered, txPow1, RSSI2Unfiltered, txPow2, RSSI3Unfiltered, txPow3);
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putParcelable("b",center);

                    Intent intent00 = new Intent();
                    intent00.putExtras(args);
                    startActivity(intent00);
```

And I want to put it in the WayfindingOverlayActivity.class

```
  private IALocationListener mListener = new IALocationListenerSupport() {

        public void onLocationChanged(IALocation location) {
            Log.d(TAG, "NEW" + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
            if (mMap == null) {
                return;
            }



            final LatLng center = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLatitude());

            
            final int newFloor = location.getFloorLevel();
            if (mFloor != newFloor) {
                updateRouteVisualization();
            }
            mFloor = newFloor;

            showLocationCircle(center, location.getAccuracy());

            if (mCameraPositionNeedsUpdating) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(center, 15.5f));
                mCameraPositionNeedsUpdating = false;
            }
        }

    };
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // prevent the screen going to sleep while app is on foreground
        findViewById(android.R.id.content).setKeepScreenOn(true);

        // instantiate IALocationManager
        mIALocationManager = IALocationManager.create(this);


        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMapAsync(this);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, RangingActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(myIntent);
 //       Intent intent99 = getIntent();
 //       LatLng ll = intent99.getParcelableExtra("b");
        //LatLng center = new LatLng(ll.latitude,ll.longitude);
       // final double latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitude");
//       Log.d(TAG,"Location" + ll.latitude+ "Location" + ll.longitude);
    }
```

With the comented sections I tried to pass it but it was with no success . Please help
Thank you!

Comment: `Intent intent00 = new Intent(this, another activity.class);
                    intent00.putExtras(args);
                    startActivity(intent00);`

Comment: it says that can not resolve the constructor 'Intent(anonymus org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier , java.lang.Class<com.indooratlas.android.sdk.examples.wayfinding.WayfindingOverlayActivity>)' when I try to make the change you have said . Thank you

Comment: If you are able to start an activity like you do here:    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, RangingActivity.class); thyen you can start any activity. You only have to care that the `this`is a valid Context.

Comment: `can not resolve the constructor 'Intent(anonymus org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier `. So the `this`is a RangeNotifier. Not a RangingActivity.class as you said where your `center`was. Try `RangingActivity.this` if the notifyer is a part of that activity.

Comment: This resolved the error . And one more question please, in the WayfindingOverlayActivity class where I want to pass the LatLng I should let how I wrote? Or how? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand what you want.

Comment: In the activity where I want to pass this value , What I have to write? it s ok what I writted and now is marked as comment?

Comment: Bundle bundle = getIntent().getData(); or something like that. (I have no code at hand at the moment). You want to pass a bundle. That is pretty standard. You should be able to find plenty of examples.

Comment: `In the activity where I want to pass this value` That was confusing. You ment `In the activity where I want to receive this value`.

Comment: Oh yes , sorry . My English was bad . Sorry sorry. Yes , this is it! Thank you very much !! I solved it .